# MediaWiki non-theme-dependent CSS

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

I use MediaWiki and I want to add some **non-theme-dependent** or "global" CSS; basically some `display:none`s,

It's a quick way to customize CSS without creating **sub-themes** (what I'd like to avoid due to a minimalist approach; it's also practically redundant for me in everything else beside CSS).

How can this be done without installing any extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can add global CSS without installing any extensions by navigating to `Common.css`:

```
https://example.com/MediaWiki:Common.css
```

Funny that I didn't find the file in the **file tree** of the MediaWiki directory.